# not found error not handling in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i am trying to put customError tag in web.config file.. 
still it doesn't redirect to default url

http://www.lacopainn.com/page/2/?p=dbasndwefxknyafc&wpmp_switcher=mobile

here is my site. when we enter this url it shows error of

**Not Found**

The requested document was not found on this server.

how can i handle this error and redirect to detault page??

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put following tag under System.web tag in your webconfig file

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="On">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="default.aspx" />
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: its not working.. i have already tried this.. any other way pls ?

Comment: can you share your webconfig file to check what is going wrong. There also exist the possibility of the error module not being installed in IIS 7 as it is an optional item when you install IIS 7 under windows feature installation.